# Extract audio stream from http site (online radio)

Tags: http, stream

I'm new here so firstly sorry for all my mistakes.
I'm trying to add one more radio station to my raspberryPi based online radio player (of course for private use only). It is an polish radio, radio Wawa. Here is the official site and stream: https://www.eskago.pl/radio/wawa But unfortunately on official site there are some adds before stream start (and I don't see the stream url :( ). I found an unofficial site with stream: https://pl.radioonline.fm/sluchac/Radio-WAWA Here there is no adds but still it's some complicated for me to extract stream which would be useful to play e.g. in omxplayer.
I found that the url for stream is http://waw.ic.smcdn.pl/t050-1.aac but the site is adding to this url a timestamp and a mistery hash. Full request looks like:
http://waw.ic.smcdn.pl/t050-1.aac?timestamp=1546208561&hash=25d2e0deebc354c9e9b5c37b74b64f21
Now is the question: is it possible to play this with command line only (the best option with omxplayer)? And how?
Thanks.

Comment: This question is off topic, please try to post your question on the www.superuser.com forums, you'll probably get more help there. This site is for programming based questions.

Comment: Sure, thanks for hint. And sorry for offtop.